# Вставить столбец в DataFrame с формулой на основе значений из других столбцов

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame, допустим, вот такой:

```
ID  ead recovery
1   10  15
2   20  15
3   30  40
4   0   12
5   nan nan
```

В реальном DataFrame 80 тыс. строк.

Необходимо добавить столбец "new", в который вносится формула: `max(df.ead - df.recovery, 0)`, а также столбец "new1" с формулой `scalar * min(df.ead, df.recovery) / df.ead`, где `scalar=0.03` чтобы получился следующий результат:

```
ID  ead recovery new new1
1   10  15       0   0.03
2   20  15       5   0.0225
3   30  40       0   0.03
4   0   12       0   0
5   nan nan      nan nan
```

Нашел на просторах следующий вариант:

```
def foo(ead, recovery):
    return max(ead - recovery, 0)
def foo1(ead, recovery):
    return 0 if ead==0 or ead==np.nan else 0.03 * min(ead,recovery) / ead

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x.ead, x.recovery), axis=1)
df['new1'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo1(x.ead, x.recovery), axis=1)
```

Результата достигаю, но время исполнения кода за счет вычисления этого столбца значительно увеличивается. Предполагаю, что сам по себе вариант с `.apply()` не сильно оптимален.

Может быть, есть варианты как-то по другому добавить вычисляемый столбец на основе условия?

Comment: `df['new'] = df.ead - df.recovery; df.loc[df['new']<0, 'new'] = 0`

Comment: `df['new'] = np.where((df.ead - df.recovery).ge(0), df.ead - df.recovery, 0)`

Comment: первый вариант интересный, только вот основная формула на самом деле более сложная, в ней в том числе сидит деление на df.ead и в предложенном варианте ломаюсь на первом шаге при делении на 0.

Comment: если надо делить на 0, то при любой формуле будет не очень :)

Comment: кстати, если если делить при помощи .divide(df.ead), то по идее должно вернуть inf

Comment: советую указать сразу более сложную формулу - решение может сильно зависеть от нюансов ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df
   ID   ead  recovery  new
0   1  10.0        15    0
1   2  20.0        15    5
2   3  30.0        40    0
3   5   0.0        25    0
4   4   NaN        25    0

>>> (0.03 * df[['ead','recovery']].min(1) / df.ead).fillna(0)
0    0.0300
1    0.0225
2    0.0300
3    0.0000
4    0.0000
dtype: float64
```